# MVC3 radiobuttons do not behave like they should

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a problem that's starting to drive me crazy.. I've narrowed my problem down to the following test case:

Model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public bool TestBool { get; set; }
}
```

Index View:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
@Html.Action("Test")
```

Test View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Test_GUI.Models.TestModel>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
<table>
     @Html.EditorForModel()
</table>
<input type="submit" value="OK"/>
}
```

Editor template;

```
<tr>
<td>
    Yes
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.TestBool, Model.TestBool)
</td>
<td>
    No
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.TestBool, !Model.TestBool)
</td>
```

In the TestController, I create two instances of TestModel with a value of false and pass them to the view. But the radiobuttons are rendered as checked, and they also return as true if I post the form.. 
I've tried many other ways to display the radiobuttons, but nothing seems to work. This seems like to correct way to do it. 
I must be able use the current value of the boolean, so I cannot use fixed true or false values in the view. If I do use a fixed true/false, I do get the correct values on the form and in the controller after posting the form..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<td>
    Yes
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.TestBool, true)
</td>
<td>
    No
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.TestBool, false)
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you, but like I say in the last part of my post, that does work, but I need to be able to use the current value. (in the real scenario I'm displaying a datagrid that can be edited and saved)

Comment: @Hanno, what current value? Just set the TestBool property in your controller action and the correct radio button will be checked automatically.

Comment: Could you explain how to achieve this? Because I have to pass some value as second parameter, but how do I pass the current value in a way that works?

Comment: @Hanno, I don't understand what you are asking. If you use the code in my answer you could then have a controller action with the following signature: `[HttpPost] public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<TestModel> model) { ... }` in which you will be able to fetch the selected values.

Comment: After checking the page source, things look even weirder.. The value attributes are set correctly, but the checked attributes are wrong.. So for example I set one item to false, and one item to true, both are displayed as checked, but their values are set correctly. If I change the radiobutton values, the page posts the original values and not the 'checked' values..

Comment: @Hanno, did you use the code I have shown in my answer? That should work. I have tested it.